# Calling model methods from django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my models, you will see that I have a model method. I want to be able to call the `add_time()` method from the REST API. How can I make that possible? What should the API request look like when making the call to that method?

*views.py*

```
class ReviewDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewDetailsSerializer
```

*serializers.py*

```
class ReviewDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'
```

*models.py*

```
class Review(models.Model):
    due = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    time_studied = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    def add_time(self, time_studied):
        self.time_studied += time_studied
        return self.save()
```

This is my first time making APIs and perhaps there is a fundamental aspect of RESTful APIs that I'm just not getting.

Thank you taking the time to read my question.

Comment: You didn't create the views yet, your logic goes there as normal django views but extend APIView

Comment: @ahmed it appears that I incorrectly labels my file names. Sorry. I fixed that. There is a view there that subclasses RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Comment: You're extending an API view class, <kbd>ctrl + L-click</kbd> to see what methods it has and override as needed, don't forget to call super()

Comment: it has a `.get` `.post` and other methods to override as needed

Answer (score 1):

```
class ReviewDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewDetailsSerializer
    
    # override this, this view supports GET method
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        main_response = super().get(request, **kwargs)
        # do something and return a proper HttpResponse instance

        return main_response
```

Comment: I suspected I might need to override the `post` method but never would have guessed that I would be doing anything with `get`. Since there is data being changed, would I not want to override `post` instead? Or would I want to make an entirely new method beside either of them?

Comment: Retrieve uses GET method, the data is a query parameter

Answer (score -1):

models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    due = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    time_studied = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    
    def add_time(self, time_studied):
        self.time_studied += time_studied
        return self.save()
```

serializers.py

```
class ReviewDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    add_time = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['id', 'due', 'time_studied', 'correct', 'add_time']

    def get_add_time(self, obj):
        return obj.add_time()
```

Comment: `add_time()` missing the argument. This will raise an error

Comment: I don't get that. BTW, the statement **`obj.add_time()`** will raise an error as ***`TypeError: add_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'time_studied'
`***

Comment: If I assume that I just add `time` as a parameter on the `get_add_time`, and adjust the call to the model method accordingly, then I suspect this could still work. If it does, how would the client call this method?

Comment: You can use django `signals` in this case. for more information, you can take a look at this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/)